# How to find where my bot is running (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot was giving me two outputs or more every time I gave it a command (for example, I said .ping and said the bot's ping twice). I figured out that the problem was the bot was running somewhere else, so I regenerated the token and everything worked fine for a little while until the problem started happening again. I kept regenerating the token and it fixed the problem for a bit. Is there a way I can find where else my bot is running and shut it down there?

Comment: Which program do you use to code?

Comment: I use Atom to code

Comment: Could you provide more details about this problem? like a code? envs?

Comment: So usually my bot gives one response like if you say .ping, it would give you the bot's ping once. But recently, every few hours I have to regenerate the token because if I don't, the bot will start sending two responses instead of one, and I have no idea why. My bot isn't running anywhere else. There is no error code or anything, it just gives multiple outputs sometimes, and regenerating its token helps for a little while before the problem resumes.

Comment: If the bot sends the message twice, you have two instances of your bot running. Make sure that you start the software and the bot only once.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close all running instances of the bot, just use `exit()`.

```py
@commands.is_owner() #make sure no one else uses it
@bot.command()
async def stop_bot(ctx):
    exit()
```

This will close all the instances of the bot.